# Chrome extension : how to detect click in background process?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am devlopping a google chrome extension
I have a background process and a popup window.

I want to not use the popup window any more, but instead **open a web browser window when chrome extension button is clicked**:

How do I do that : How do I detect the click inside background.js ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is quite easy

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
   // The action icon has been clicked
});
```

You'll have to declare the extension as a browser action in your manifest and remove the popup option